# Reading a file stream being concurrently written by another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, java-io

I have a Postgres `BlobInputStream` which is bound to a database transaction and I need to transfer it to a client which is requesting it via an HTTP request.

To avoid slow clients to starve database transactions, I want to flush the stream to disk and concurrently let the client read from the disk: this way, the transaction will end when the stream is written to the disk even if the client is still reading from the file.

Obviously, I don't want the client to wait the whole stream to be flushed to disk before start reading.

This is my code so far:

```
public void transferStreamToChannel(InputStream stream, SinkChannel channel) {
    try {
        // Create a temporary file to buffer to stream transfer, so that slow readers won't
        // starve the transaction.
        var tmp = Files.createTempFile(StreamTransferInitiator.class.getSimpleName(),
                Thread.currentThread().getName());
        var tos = Files.newOutputStream(tmp);

        var executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(() -> {
            try (var fis = Files.newInputStream(tmp, StandardOpenOption.DELETE_ON_CLOSE)) {
                var out = Channels.newOutputStream(channel);
                fis.transferTo(out);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                this.getLogger().error("Error writing to disk", e);
            }
        });

        stream.transferTo(tos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        this.getLogger().error("Error reading stream", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            stream.close();
            channel.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            this.getLogger().error("Error closing stream", e);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that the executor will find an empty file and will close before the database stream has been fully flushed.

How can I connect the two operations so that the transfer to the client is aware of more data is still to be written to disk?